# Questions autoload like Super User

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, live-refresh

Is there any option/setting that I need to turn on to get auto load questions (something like push) in my interesting tab without refreshing whole page every time?

I recently noticed, that such a feature is available on the Super User. It shows as

> 3 questions with new activity

Answer (score 4):

Due to the heavy question load on Stack Overflow, this is only available for the specific tag pages on Stack Overflow.

Visit the tag you want to observe and the page gets updated if new questions arrive or get active.

[image: Tags]

I do that for my favourite tags and sort by *Newest*. Then you get notified very fast about new questions and can answer before everyone else ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer, may i know which are all the tags that have this option.

Comment: All have. Visit the tag page and select one or click on a tag that you favoured.